# UICollection View reloadData() not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, collectionview

I have a problem of reloadData() not working for my collection view. I have three collection views and I have used this code to attempt to reload the data everytime the view is opened.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.newArrivalsCollectionView.reloadData()
    self.recommendedTitleCollectionView.reloadData()
    self.popularTitlesCollectionVIew.reloadData()
}
```

The problem is that at first, the collection views display the correct number of cells and the image (it has a UIImage inside the cell). However, when I press the button to go back to the view with these collection views. It apparently reuses the cells and creates more of the same cell. I have attempted to reload the data in the collection view function that creates these cell however it creates an error.

**EDIT:**

I have set the view controller as the Data Source & Delegate for all 3 view controllers under the viewDidLoad() method. Also, the cells are interactive, when touched they should do something (ie. go to another view), so it shouldn't just hide the unwanted reused cells but remove them completely.

I also realised every-time I reopen the view, it would add the same number of cells to the current number of cells. For example, if originally, the collection view has 2 different cells, it would recreate those 2 cells, and now there would be 4 cells of the same 2 types of cells. If I do this again, there would be 6 cells of the same 2 types of cells. I reckon that it was with my array of books, so I tried setting it empty in viewDidAppear() method, however, it still doesn't work.

Other Following Codes:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if collectionView == newArrivalsCollectionView {
        return bookNewArrivalDataBase.count
    }
    else if collectionView == popularTitlesCollectionVIew
    {
        return bookPopularDatabase.count
    }
    else {
        return bookRecommendedDatabase.count
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    //if it is a new arrival


    if collectionView == newArrivalsCollectionView{

    let newArrivalsCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "newArrivalsCell", for: indexPath) as! bookNewArrivalsCollectionViewCell

    //sets the book that is being displayed
    let bookCell = bookNewArrivalDataBase[indexPath.row]

    // set the photo of the book that the new arrival cell is at
    newArrivalsCell.setBookImage(bookCell)


    return newArrivalsCell
    }

else if collectionView == popularTitlesCollectionVIew {


    let popularTitlesCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "popularTitlesCell", for: indexPath) as! bookPopularTitlesCollectionViewCell

    //sets the book that is being displayed
    let bookCell = bookPopularDatabase[indexPath.row]

    // set the photo of the book that the new arrival cell is at
    popularTitlesCell.setBookImage(bookCell)
    return popularTitlesCell

    }
    else {

        //create recommended title cell
        let recommendedTitlesCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "recommendedTitlesCell", for: indexPath) as! bookRecommendedTitlesCollectionViewCell

        let bookCell = bookRecommendedDatabase[indexPath.row]

        // set the photo of the book
        recommendedTitlesCell.setBookImage(bookCell)

        return recommendedTitlesCell
    }

} // end of cellforitemat
```

So, how can I reload the collection view everytime the view appears again so that it would not reuse the cells originally loaded at the first time the view appears?

Comment: Are you able to provide more information (e.g. your IUCollectionViewDataSource ... ) ?

Comment: Did you set `dataSource` properties of your collection views? Provide the code for your data source methods - `numberOfItemsInSection`, `cellForItemAt` and `numberOfSections`

Comment: @T.Werb I have added the information that you need

Comment: @mag_zbc Yes I have set the dataSource as the viewcontroller of where the collection views are. I have included the code that creates the cells in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my own problem as it lies in the array database itself and not the collection view being unable to reload the data. Apparently, I just had to reset the database every time.

The key learning point is

> Similar collection view cells does not necessarily mean that it is duplicating previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems with your delegate methods of collection view :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return number
}

func register(AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String)

func cellForItem(at: IndexPath)
```

Fixing the methods will solve the issue else try using prepareForReuse() method in your cell class and set values to nil of the imageview image .ex :

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    imageview.image = nil

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to all reload data put into

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
      // your function to reloadData
}
```